# eclipse maven error - No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am trying to mavenise a project and it throws me error saying the plugin could not be resolved. I was able to run mvn install from command line and it works perfectly. While invoking mvn install from eclipse (Helios), it gives me the error as given below. I verified the jars are present in my local repository (c:\users....m2\repository)

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to construct build plan for: Unnamed - myapp:myapp-ecom:war:1.0
Id: myapp:myapp-ecom:war:1.0
task-segment: [install]. Reason: Failed to resolve plugin for mojo binding: org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1:listapps
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getLifecycleBindings(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:414)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmentForProject(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:235)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:191)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:149)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute_aroundBody0(DefaultMaven.java:223)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute_aroundBody1$advice(DefaultMaven.java:304)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:1)
at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute_aroundBody2(MavenEmbedder.java:904)
at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute_aroundBody3$advice(MavenEmbedder.java:304)
at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute(MavenEmbedder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.iam.core.embedder.internal.EclipseMaven.executeRequest(EclipseMaven.java:325)
at org.eclipse.iam.core.embedder.internal.EclipseMavenRequest.run(EclipseMavenRequest.java:160)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.LifecyclePlannerException: Failed to resolve plugin for mojo binding: org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1:listapps
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.findForkModifiers(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.addForkedLifecycleModifiers(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:179)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.constructBuildPlan_aroundBody0(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.constructBuildPlan_aroundBody1$advice(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:403)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.constructBuildPlan(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:1)
at org.eclipse.iam.core.embedder.internal.EclipseMavenBuildPlanner.constructBuildPlan(EclipseMavenBuildPlanner.java:43)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getLifecycleBindings(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:400)
... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.loader.PluginLoaderException: Failed to load plugin. Reason: No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [9.0,11.0)
weblogic:weblogic:jar:null

from the specified remote repositories:
codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org),
snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
central (http://central)
Path to dependency:
1) org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.9.1


at org.apache.maven.plugin.loader.DefaultPluginLoader.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginLoader.java:89)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.loader.DefaultPluginLoader.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginLoader.java:52)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.plan.DefaultBuildPlanner.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultBuildPlanner.java:322)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.OverConstrainedVersionException: No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [9.0,11.0)
weblogic:weblogic:jar:null

from the specified remote repositories:
codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org),
snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
central (http://central)
Path to dependency:
1) org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.9.1


at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:496)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:394)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:337)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getPluginArtifacts(DefaultPluginManager.java:436)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:279)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:186)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.loader.DefaultPluginLoader.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginLoader.java:79)
... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are hitting [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2742) or a similar one. Looks like your pom is having a version range for the weblogic-maven-plugin dependency. You could try changing it and see if that helps.

Comment: I have specified a specific version in my pom.xml. However your answer was an eyeopener. The pom file that comes along with weblogic-maven-plugin mentions a dependency to a version range which creates the issue. I changed the version manually in the .pom file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse >> Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use the m2eclipse plugin. This uses an embedded maven 3 version (see Preferences -> Maven -> Installation) which might be a different version than running maven from command line.

You should add your external maven installation here and use this to get the same results in eclipse as in command line.

I do not know exactly about the changes between maven 2 and 3 but heard about different handling of SNAPSHOT versions when specifying version ranges.

Comment: I do not see any section for maven installation in my eclipse (Helios).